# Google directions API limit results by bus company

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google directions API to get bus journeys. I would like to have results limited to a given bus company. I was not able to find anything in the API doc that would allow me to so. Is there any workaround / non public API that is able to accomplish it ?

Answer (score 2):

As of now there's no property that would allow your Directions Request to limit to a single bus company / transit agency.

You can choose to display only certain transit agencies by checking the response of your Directions Request and manually filtering by `agencies.name` for example. Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#TransitStop).

But there is still a chance for routes to be missing certain steps if you manually filtered out a bus ride from a different transit agency, and the route requires you to walk/go to a different bus stop that is also not being handled by your target agency. So be careful with that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got that far as well. But was hoping there was some work around as I am hitting that issue where journey with agency I need is not returned. But it exists does exists it just not in top results :-(

Comment: As your primary request is not yet available, I would suggest that you file a Feature Request in Google's public issue tracker detailing the pain-point you just mentioned! Here's the link: https://issuetracker.google.com